# Get the instance name of the object no the object type name in C# 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, reflection

Assume this type:

```
public class Car { }
```

And I create an instance of that:

```
Car myCar = new Car();

Target target = new Target();
target.Model = myCar;
```

And this is another Type:

```
public class Target {

   public object Model { get; set; }

   string GetName(){

     //Use Model and return myCar in this Example
   }

}
```

As I showed in code the `GetName` method must use an object type (`Model`) and returned the name of instance that is myCar in this example? what is your suggestion is there any way to do this?

**Update**
How about this:

```
public class Car {

  public string Title { get; set; }

}
```

And I pass to target: `target.Model = Car.Title`

And `GetName()` method returned `Title` ?

Comment: Variable name doesn't make and should not make any sense in business logic

Comment: So if you change the variable name, things break?

Comment: Why is `Model` just an object instead of a `Car` (or a subclass of it)?

Comment: It's unclear what the point of `Target` is.  But you'd want to do `target.Model = myCar` and then probably later cast it back to a `Car` and access the `Title` property.  So something like `Car car = target.Model as Car; if (car != null) { // Do something with your car object }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Why? Because `myCar` is only a *name* for your `Car` instance *inside* the scope which you set up the variable for. What gets saved to `target.Model` is a *reference* to the `Car` instance. So, after your sample code, both `myCar` and `target.Model` reference the same instance of `Car`, just with different names. The names themselves are rather unimportant to the execution of the program, it's just a trick we use to make talking about instances easier.

Comment: I Update Question what you think now?

Answer (score 5):

Objects do not have a name, unless they explicitly have a way to store their name. `myCar` is a local variable - the object itself (the `Car`) **does not know** that you are referring to it by the name `myCar`. To illustrate:

```
Car myCar = new Car();
Car car2 = myCar;
Car car3 = myCar;
```

Now all three variables refer to the *same* `Car`.

If you want cars to have names, you could do

```
public class Car 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then assign and read whatever name you want it to have.

Comment: Well, you could always return a list of names... just kidding ;-) +1.

Comment: I Update Question what you think now?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "name of the instance". What you're saying about is the name of the specific reference to the object; there could be many references to the same object, all with different names. Also, linking code and data (i.e. relying on the variable name) is a bad practice.

If you want `Car` to have some name, then name it **explicitly**:

```
public class Car {
    public string Name { get; set; }
} 

Car myCar = new Car { Name = "myCar" };
```