# How to code "one sub for many subs" in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I have n Labels on Form, e.g: Label1, Label2,..., Labeln. Normally, when I write Click event for all Labels:

```
    Private Sub Label1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click
        Msgbox "1"
    End Sub
```

`Private Sub Label2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click
    Msgbox "2"
End Sub

Private Sub Labeln_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Labeln.Click
    Msgbox "n"
End Sub`

Writting is very complex when n is large!

Now, I want to write the code simply to click to Lablei and generate "i" (one proceduce to many proceduces). How to handle it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: That’s what arrays are for. Do you know how to use them?

Comment: `Handles Label2.Click, Label3.Click, Labelx.Click, Labely.Click....`  extend one of the click events to handle them all

Comment: Thanks, can you help me do specifically?

Comment: Use a ListBox or ListView instead.

Comment: Oh, no, by my reason I cant use other controls to instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
Private Sub Labeln_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
       Handles Label1.Click, Label2.Click, Label3.Click '...
    Dim l As Label = DirectCast(sender, Label)
    Msgbox l.Name
End Sub
```

If n is *very* large, skip the `Handles` portion of the method and do this in your form load:

```
For Each l As Label in Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
    AddHandler l.Click, AddressOf Labeln_Click
Next
```

Comment: I want to get the index of Labels, the code above is used to get the name of Label. Can you support more with this problem? Thanks.

Comment: @user3479750 What makes you think the labels have an index at all? What will you use the index for?

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically assign the event handlers when you create your labels using `AddHandler`:

```
Sub test()
    Dim label1 As New Label()
    AddHandler label1.Click, AddressOf HandleLabelClick
    Me.Controls.Add(label1)
End Sub
```

Here's the event handler:

```
Sub HandleLabelClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MsgBox(DirectCast(sender, Label).Name)
End Sub
```

Comment: What will I have to do? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks you. But I want to get the index of Labels, how to do this?

Comment: How are you adding your labels in the first place?  At run time (as I've shown above) or at design time?  What index are you referring to?

Comment: Thanks, I have n Labels ready on my Form (default is Label1, Label2,..., Labeln), I create them at design-time, the index of them is my imagination for them! Label1->1; Label2->2;...; Labeln->n.

Comment: Okay, you could still simplify things by coding the handlers like I showed you.  To get your index, use `Substring` in your event handler: `MsgBox(DirectCast(sender, Label).Name.Substring(5))`.  However, this assumes that you've set the name of your label using the `.Name` property.  You can't refer to the instance name itself anywhere (see this for reason why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205427/get-the-instance-name-of-the-object-no-the-object-type-name-in-c-sharp-4-0).

Answer (score 2):

I would not use the handler and instead make a custom control that inherits from the framework; it would have this message box as a standard feature of the control.

Create a new class as such:

```
Public Class MyLabel : Inherits Label
    Protected Overrides Sub OnClick(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnClick(e)

        MsgBox(Me.Name)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Once compiled, it will show up in your toolbox. Paint it on the screen and see it work.

Comment: You could also make the value to display a property on your custom control. This would be simple and allow greater configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Per other answers, you would do best to explicitly add a handler. If the labels are added at runtime (dynamically added at server), you can attach to the AddHandler definition. If the controls are built at design time (defined in markup), handle the OnClick event of each to the same handler. Alternately, for controls built at design time, you can chain each control to the Handles definition of one method.

To get the numerical value, you could use Substring as long as the IDs are, at minimum, of consistent on the text part. Or, you could use regex.match as long as there are no other numbers in the name. I like to append numerical portions of IDs to the end of the ID following an underscore. This allows me to not care what the text portion is, use .split("_"), and gives me the number. This also allows me to append multiple number values with multiple underscores in the event I am using them to identify an ancestor - descendent relationship of objects related to the control (i.e. datatables used to create and fill the control).

You have many options, most of them being equal. Have you found a solution to fit your specific needs yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like that:

```
Private Sub OnClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click, Label2.Click, Label3.Click, Label4.Click    
  messagebox.show(directcast(sender, label).text)        
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim i As Integer
Private Sub Form1_Load() Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each l As Label In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()
        AddHandler l.Click, Sub()
                                i = CInt(l.Name.Replace("Label", ""))
                                MsgBox(i)
                            End Sub
    Next
End Sub
```